# Feeding grid transformers via secondary, primary disconnected

Tags: transformer, step-up, microgrid

I am interested in how transformers are used in the electrical grid, with a view of one day building an isolated "microgrid" for educational purposes.  I am however having some difficulty getting some concrete answers for how transformers - as used in the electrical grid - work.

There are a number of questions here about running a transformer "backwards" (using the secondary winding as the input) with two common answers.  One is that transformers can be run either way with no special consideration, and the other is that the winding impedance is often much lower on the secondary side, so running a transformer backwards may overload the source AC supply.

Is this true?  If I took say a 50 kVA transformer, 11 kV primary 415 V secondary, and fed 415 VAC into the secondary side, would it try to draw some large current well beyond what you would expect as inrush current?  Or would it simply start at the high inrush current level and quickly drop back to a current draw similar to that model's "no load" rating?  How is this different to connecting the transformer normally on the primary/HV side?  Wouldn't that also have a similar inrush current (though obviously smaller due to the higher voltage)?

My reason for asking is that I can't get a definite answer as to whether you can use a large step down transformer in reverse, and if you can, whether an initial surge is all you have to deal with or whether there's more to it than that.  I suppose what I am getting at, is whether there is actually a design and performance difference between two transformers that are otherwise equal, except one has an 11 kV primary, 415 V secondary and the other has a 415 V primary, 11 kV secondary?

Taking this a step further, if I want to buy a small transformer for my isolated microgrid, is it a problem buying one that is too large for what I need?  For instance it looks like I can source 10 kVA 11 kV transformers from China relatively cheaply, but if I only have say 1 kVA of power available, will it draw too much current even after the inrush current has settled down?

My limited understanding is that there will be an initial spike in current until a magnetic field has been generated inside the transformer, and after this the current draw will drop back to the transformer's "no load" rated current, only increasing again if power is used on the other side of the transformer.  So I could "run" a 10 kVA transformer on only 1 kVA, as long as the power source can handle the transformer's inrush current.  I thought this would apply whether you feed the transformer's primary or secondary, but after reading some other answers here, I am now not so sure!

Comment: It's possible that in a step down transformer design, in order to help the transformer meet output regulation specifications, it might over produce voltage on light loads by making the step-down turns ratio slightly less than that for an ideal transformer. For a step up transformer the step up ratio may be slightly increased for the same reason. This means you have two slightly different transformer turn ratios.

Comment: In addition to the inrush current, another disadvantage of using a transformer rated 10X the intended kVA load is high magnetizing current. I believe the magnetizing current and other design details should be available from the manufacturer. However, to some extent, the details available may be proportional to the price.